# jQuery mobile listview - add some text on the right

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've just started using jquery mobile, so please bear with me. I'm trying to create a list view with the price of the item aligned on the right (the description of the item is aligned to the left -- this part works fine).

I've searched the internet and can't find anything that might help me.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="home" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
            <h1>For sale</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="false">
            <li><a href="#itemA">A</a></li>   <!-- want to put a right-aligned price in here!-->
            <li><a href="#itemB">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#itemC">C</a></li>
            <li><a href="#itemD">D</a></li>
            <li><a href="#itemE">E</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

another idea: you could add a 2 column grid, see here http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-grids.html

> **Two column grids**
>
> To build a two-column (50/50%) layout, start with a container with a
>   class of ui-grid-a, and add two child containers inside it classed
>   with ui-block-a for the first column and ui-block-b for the second:
>
> ```
> <div class="ui-grid-a">
>     <div class="ui-block-a"><strong>I'm Block A</strong> and text inside will wrap</div>
>     <div class="ui-block-b"><strong>I'm Block B</strong> and text inside will wrap</div>
> </div><!-- /grid-a -->
> ```
>
> Grid classes can be applied to any container

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for something like count bubbles, which are displayed on [this page](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-count.html) of the documentation. You can replace the counts with prices.

The [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/docs-lists.html) states:

> To add a count indicator to the right of the list item, wrap the number in an element with a class of `ui-li-count`

Comment: I was hoping to avoid count bubbles. The text is a bit small... Also, do count bubbles do decimals?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can put whatever you want in them. You can also use `ui-li-aside` but I'm not sure what that would look like. If you dislike how small the text is, add another class to the div/span you're encapsulating your prices with and with css increase the font size to whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

you can override the CSS as described [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/themes.html)

> **Overriding themes**
>
> The themes are meant as a solid starting point, but are meant to be
>   customized. Since everything is controlled by CSS, it's easy to use a
>   web inspector tool to identify the style properties you want to
>   modify.

in your case add this

```
 <style>
 .ui-page .ui-content .ui-listview .ui-li {
   text-align: right;
 }
 </style>
```

and you will get this result
[image]

**EDIT**: I just reread your question, you like to have the description on the left and only the price on the right, probably you should follow the advice of Jeff then...

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution on the [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/lists/lists-formatting.html).

You can use something like this within your `li` element:

```
<p class="ui-li-aside ui-li-desc"><strong>2.75</strong></p>
```